# Change Laravel Relationship Output Structure

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I have Role and Permission models with

Role.php

```
public function permissions()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Permissions');
}
```

And if I call

```
return Role::with('permissions')->get()
```

it will return

```
[{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "training_vendor",
      "display_name": "Training Vendor",
      "description": "Role for vendor",
      "created_at": "2016-06-23 08:05:47",
      "updated_at": "2016-06-23 08:05:47",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "permission_id": 1,
          "role_id": 2
        },
        {
          "permission_id": 2,
          "role_id": 2
        },
        {
          "permission_id": 3,
          "role_id": 2
        },
        {
          "permission_id": 4,
          "role_id": 2
        },
        {
          "permission_id": 5,
          "role_id": 2
        }
}]
```

Is it possible to change the "permissions" structure to something like these?

```
[{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "training_vendor",
      "display_name": "Training Vendor",
      "description": "Role for vendor",
      "created_at": "2016-06-23 08:05:47",
      "updated_at": "2016-06-23 08:05:47",
      "permissions": [1,2,3,4,5]            
}]
```

Comment: Your best bet might be to map over the collection and change the permissions property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an array (as title says), use [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-toarray) method:

```
return Role::with('permissions')->get()->toArray();
```

It will convert the collection to an array.

If you need to get custom formatted JSON (as your example shows), use `toArray()`, then rebuild this array with using `foreach` or [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)/[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) methods and encode result into JSON with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

I would recommend you to send data as is (without rebuilding it's structure) to frontend or whatever and work with it there.

Comment: But... 1) the desired output format is json, and 2) that still won't change the permissions array as the OP wants.

Comment: I was confused by title of the question (which says array). I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the title. So, I have to rebuild the array after query? Is it possible to do it inside relationship method?

Answer (score 0):

I order to extract a Collection of permission IDs you can use the `pluck()` function:

```php
$permissionIds = $role->permissions->pluck('permission_id');
```

You can also write a getter function in your `Role` model:

```php
public function getPermissionIds()
{
    return $this->permissions->pluck('permission_id');
}
```

and use it like:

```php
$permissionIds = $role->getPermissionIds();
```

You can even override the magic `__get()` function:

```php
public function __get($attr)
{
    if ($attr === 'permissionIds') {
        return $this->getPermissionIds();
    } else {
        return parent::__get($attr);
    }
}
```

and access the permission IDs like an attribute:

```php
$permissionIds = $role->permissionIds;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.2 the returned value of models is a **Collection** instance which can be used to transform the result

```
$roles = Role::with('permissions')->get();
$roles->transform(function($role){
     $role['permissions'] = $role['permissions']->pluck('permission_id')->toArray();
     return $role;
});

return $roles;
```

This code will provide the desirable result.

**Note:** You can even chain the transform function after the get function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will help to you,

```
$role = Role::all();

    foreach ($role as $index){
        $permissions= $index->permissions;
        foreach ($permissions as $permission){
            $permissionId[] = $permission->permission_id;
        }
        unset($index->permissions);

        $index['all_permissions']= $permissionId;
    }   

    return response()->json($role, 200);
```

This is work for me. So check for your code.